# How to avoid circular reference when excel cell update

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a set of functions in c++ which can be called by excel. However, these functions are asynchronous, therefore no immediate return values available. Once a result is available I used a callback function through VBA which update the result to the relevant cell which called the functions.

But, here I'm having circular function calling problem, because when I update the cell. excel automatically call the original function once again. Please help me to get around this problem

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about the data flow of your program it's impossible to answer in detail.  When are c++ functions called, what data is passed to them and when are you updating the relevant cell?

Regardless, how are you calling the C++ functions?  If it's via VBA, try turning off automatic calculation:

```
MyWorkSheet.EnableCalculation = False
```

and then turning it back on at the end of the callback:

```
MyWorkSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better, if you can put a code sample explaining what you are exactly trying to do.

what do you mean by

> pass the current cell reference

if my understanding is correct, you are trying to pass return value of the function to the function itself again. This is a circular reference. because, when the function returns a value, the cell value get updated which then cause re-evaluate any function that has the updated cell reference as a input parameter which result in your function to call in a loop!